# How do I paginate with an already modified URL?

Tags: php, pagination

I have a search bar that returns values and I want to paginate the results, however, my url is already `search.php?result=whateverresultis` and I tried simply putting `?page=whatever` after it and all my results went away.  This is my code currently:

```
    <?php
include("config.php");
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['result']);
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>Envy Dayz | <?php echo $search; ?></title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="searchleft">
</div>
<div class="search">
<center>
<form method="get" action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="result" value="<?php echo $search; ?>" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php       
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shop
    WHERE MATCH (name,description,keywords) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)") or die(mysql_error());

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($data);

if ($num_rows == "1") {
    echo "Returned 1 result.";
} else { echo "Returned ".$num_rows." results."; }

while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    $name = stripslashes($info['name']);
    $desc = stripslashes($info['description']);
    $desc = substr($desc, 0, 150);
    $price = stripslashes($info['price']);
    Print "<div style=\"width:600px; height:150px; border:1px solid black; overflow:hidden\"><div style=\"height:148px; width:25%; border:1px solid red; float:left\"><center><img src=\"".$picture."\" height=\"120\" width=\"120\" style=\"margin-top:15px\" /></center></div><div style=\"height:150px; width:50%; border:1px solid blue; float:left; text-overflow: ellipsis; padding-top:5px\"><center><font size=\"+1\"><b><a href=\"result.php?product=".urlencode($name)."\">".$name."</b></a></font><br><br>".$desc."...</center></div><div style=\"height:150px; width:24%; border:1px solid green; float:left\"><center><h1>$".$price."</h1><button>Add to Cart</button></center></div></div>";
}
?>
```

How would I go about paginating this with 10 results on each page?

Comment: you should use `&page=whatever` not `?`

Comment: Append more variables to the query string with `&`. `?` can only be used once to mark the beginning of the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## try this

search.php?result=whateverresultis&page=whatever